# Are G-numbers equivalent to Eisenstein integers?

Tags: complex-numbers

In *100 Great Problems of Elementary Mathematics* the author terms the set of numbers $$xO+yJ:x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$$ where $J=-\omega^2$, $O=-\omega$ and $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ as G-numbers. These are used to prove Fermat's Last Theorem for $n=3$. I don't know much about rings or anything but I have also seen proofs of the same thing with similar structure using numbers of the form $x+\omega y$ which I understand is denoted $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, the Eisenstein integers. My question is if the two sets of those two kinds of numbers are equivalent or if one is a subset of the other? I notice that both have the same units ($\pm1,\pm\omega,\pm \omega^2) $ I also see that since $J^2=-O$ and $OJ=1$ if you multiply a G-number by $J$ 
$$J(xJ+yO)=-Ox+y=y+\omega x$$
Which is an Eisenstein integer, but does that mean all G-numbers are Eisenstein?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In particular, keep in mind that $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ so $J=-\omega^2=\omega+1$.

From here can you see how every G number is also an Eisenstein integer?

Comment: Oh yea if I just substitute it in $xO+yJ$ I get $y+(y-x)\omega$, so this means G-numbers are a subset of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ right?

Comment: Exactly. And the reverse direction should be pretty easy to see